# Convert PIE ELF binary into No-PIE

Tags: elf, pie

Is it possible changing few bytes for converting an elf binary from PIE to No-PIE (ELF)?
I know that in the header if `e_type` is:
 - 3 then the program is PIE
 - 2 then the program is No-PIE

So I tried to change that byte and in fact `readelf -h` shows me:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x630
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          6576 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 28
```

Then I changed the `e_entry` from `0x630` to `0x400630`.

`readelf -h` output:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x400630
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          6576 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 28
```

However if I try to launch the program it crashes.

```
$ strace ./elf-patched.exe 
execve("./elf-patched.exe", ["./elf-patched.exe"], 0x7ffe0c2b88c0 /* 66 vars */) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
[1]    7239 segmentation fault (core dumped)  strace ./elf-patched.exe
```

What other bytes should I change (If it's possible with few modifications) ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. What are you trying to achieve? And please don't repeat your question. I am looking for the reason you want to do that conversion in the first place. With some more context it's well possible there are other routes available to achieve your _actual_ goal.

Comment: My actual goal is to pwn the binary with a ROP chain, however I need the binary to be No-PIE to make the ROP chain works.

Comment: That is, you need "deterministic" addresses that you can hardcode?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with few modifications.

https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/~debray/Publications/disasm.pdf

> **2.2    Position-Independent Code**
>
> Many compilers can be instructed to emit code that does not rely on
>   being bound to any particular position in the program’s address space.
>   These code sequences are often referred to as *position-independent
>   code*(PIC). In particular, PIC sequences do not contain any relocatable
>   addresses embedded in the instructions. This property enables the code
>   to work regardless of its memory location at runtime.  Furthermore,
>   PIC does not need to be patched by the loader, enabling it to be mapped
>   as read-only data—which is useful for shared code such as dynamically
>   linked libraries [14]. When a compiler is emitting
>   position-independent code  it typically creates jump tables that are
>   also position-independent.  These tables are usually embedded in the
>   text segment of the executable and consist of a sequence of offsets
>   rather than virtual addresses.  A jump that uses the offset table
>   first loads a nearby address,<sup>1</sup> then uses this to index into the table
>   and retrieve an offset.  The offset is added to the address that was
>   previously loaded and then used in an indirect jump to reach the
>   desired destination. The problems posed by position-independent jump
>   tables are three-fold: *(i)* the offset tables, which are really no
>   different than data, appear in the instruction stream; *(ii)* the code
>   sequences that perform the indirect jumps are often complicated and
>   may not adhere to a single pattern that is easily recognizable; and
>   *(iii)* it is entirely possible that an offset table does not contain relocation entries.  Taken together,these properties make the task of
>   disassembling PIC sequences involving jump tables more difficult than
>   standard code.